# Embedding a graph into Euclidean space

Tags: graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, metric-embeddings

I want to find a map $v\mapsto \tilde v$ from the vertex set of a connected infinite graph $\Gamma$ to a Euclidean space that meets the following two conditions:

- there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $|\tilde v-\tilde w|>\varepsilon$ for any $v\ne w$, and
- $|\tilde v-\tilde w|\le 1$ for any pair of adjacent vertices $(v,w)$.

(Please note that this condition is much weaker than bi-Lipschitz embedding.)

If such map exists, then (obviously) there is a polynomial $P$ such that
$|B_R(v)|\leqslant P(R)$,
where $|B_R(v)|$ denotes the number of vertices on distance at most $R$ from $v$.

> Is it sufficient?

**Postscript.** The question is answered in "The intrinsic dimensionality of graphs" by Krauthgamer and Lee [Combinatorica, 27(5) 2007]. (Thanks to [aorq](https://mathoverflow.net/users/1079/aorq).)

Comment: Did you try Cayley graph of the integer Heisenberg group?

Comment: Krauthgamer, R. and Lee, J.R., 2007. The intrinsic dimensionality of graphs. Combinatorica, 27(5), pp.551-585.

Comment: @aorq thank you very much --- that is it! Could you make an answer from this comment, so the question will removed from unanswered?

Comment: You probably wanted to say "Euclidean space of finite dimension".

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Right, I did not mean 3-dimensional. Anyway the reference provided by aorq seems to contain a complete answer.

Comment: I did not mean 3-dimesional, I meant to exclude infinite dimensional, a Hilbert space:-)

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Euclidean space is finite-dimensional by the definition :)

Comment: This is not commonly accepted. The definition that I know is a vector space equipped with a positive definite quadratic form.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko OK it seems that you are not joking, but this is the first time I see that Euclidean space might have infinite dimension. Instead, finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces are quite common. It does not really matter, but do you have a reference that use your terminology?

Comment: @Anton Petrunin: I do not have a ready reference, will tell you when I find one (but this is what I was taught in my youth).  Wikipedia defines Euclidean space as finite-dimensional.

Comment: OK, look here, page 1: https://www.math.cmu.edu/~wn0g/2ch4a.pdf

Comment: I am sorry if my comment is not relevant. But what do you mean by map? What other extra conditions you expect from this map?a graph preserving map?Otherwise  every injective map from graph to an epsilon neighborhood of 0 works

Comment: @AliTaghavi just a map from vertex set to $\mathbb{R}^n$. By anyway the reference provided by aorq seems to contain a complete answer.